# How to copy another elements onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have been able to successfully get another elements `onclick` function by doing this:

```
document.getElementById(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text).getAttribute('onclick')
```

This gives me the exact text that I want to put into a different elements `onchange` event, so I thought I could do this:

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text).getAttribute('onclick')">
```

This does not work though. Does anyone have any ideas, I am stumped?

Comment: You shouldn't use the `onchange` property in your HTML. Instead you should bind the event to a function from a separate script -- then you won't have this problem.

Comment: What is the value of `this` in the first code snippet?

Comment: @MattBall I am using this.options[this.selectedIndex].text to get the current value of the dropdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just dump a function into an attribute like that. I recommend that you start writing [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

#### HTML

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <!-- snip -->
</select>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect');
select.onchange = function () {
    var id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text,
        clickHandler = document.getElementById(id).onclick;
    clickHandler.apply(this);
};
```

[**Demo →**](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/HYUjr/1/)

---

#### Edit re: OP's comment

> "Is there an easy way to apply this to all the selects on the page?"

Of course there is! But you need to be careful about not creating functions in a loop (it won't work).

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select'),
    numSelects = selects.length,
    i;

function setClickHandler(element) {
    element.onchange = function () {
        var id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text,
            clickHandler = document.getElementById(id).onclick;
        clickHandler.apply(this);
    }
}

for (i=0; i<numSelects; i++) {
    setClickHandler(selects[i]);
}
```

Comment: @MattBall: one more question. Is there an easy way to apply this to all the selects on the page?

Comment: @Chad: no problemo. Hopefully this has taught you something you can apply to other coding problems.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but perhaps:

```
var handler = document.getElementById(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text).getAttribute('onclick');

var selectEl = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[indexOfSelect];

selectEl.setAttribute('onClick',handler);
```

The following works (more or less the same as above, except using the 'onFocus' attribute on the `select` element):

```
var handler = document.getElementById('first').getAttribute('onclick');
var selectEl = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
selectEl.setAttribute('onfocus',handler);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/VAxw4/)

Comment: *Cough* thanks for the catch, @Matt; ...you ever have that thing where your fingers just type, automatically, and you don't pay enought attention to *what* they're typing? ...sigh. =)

Comment: @Chad: no problem at all, glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not recommended but the simplest fix that would work,

```
<select onchange="function() {document.getElementById(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text).getAttribute('onclick')();}">
```